# Problem when stored more than one int key values in sharedpreferences, any solutions?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I try to save background color and text color of an EditText in Kotlin. I mean:

```
private lateinit var sharedpreferences: SharedPreferences
val bgColorKey=0
val textColorKey=0

//SAVING CODE:
val editor = sharedpreferences.edit()
editor.putInt(bgColorKey.toString(), R.drawable.col1)
editor.putInt(textcolorKey.toString(), R.color.white)
editor.commit()

//PRINT LINE CODE:
println("NEW bgColorKey = "+sharedpreferences.getInt(bgColorKey.toString(), 0))  // I/System.out: NEW bgColorKey = 2130968609
println("NEW textcolorKey = "+sharedpreferences2.getInt(textcolorKey.toString(), 0))  // I/System.out: NEW textcolorKey = 2130968609
```

When I use putInt() method to store different color resource id's inside each key, all of them take the last value, i.e both of keys have values of `R.drawable.whitebackground`

Is this a bug? Or I make something wrong?

Comment: It is not clear what you are actually doing, but it seems, you use the same key for both.

Comment: @Henry Where is not clear can you tell? One of the keys is bgColorKey and the other is textColorKey. I created even two editors i.e "editor1.putInt" and "editor2.putInt" but when I print both the keys, they are both printing the same output. I think sharedpreference stores just 1 int value inside it, even if the keys are different.

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: It seems like that you are think that the shared preference is like a Map<Key, Values> where you can add multiple ints to one key. It's not. When you `putInt()` with the same key it replaces the int you have just added. Use different key for example `bgColorKey` and `textColorKey`.

Comment: Those aren't keys, those are variable names, referring to ``Int``s. When you use ``putInt``, you need to pass a unique ``String`` key for each one, and that's what you use to pull the values back out

Comment: A SharedPreference key is a String, not an Int, so there is some kind of fundamental miunderstanding of how it works, but we can’t help without seeing the code.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I pasted the code now

Comment: @MatiasLappalainen I pasted the code on the post now, can you look?

Comment: @Henry I pasted the code on the post now, can you look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here,

```
val bgColorKey = 0
val textColorKey = 0
```

These keys are identical (Both are 0).

In your code. The second `putInt()` will replace the first key and value pair because both of them have the same key. Each key should be different. For example,

```
val bgColorKey = 0
val textColorKey = 1
```

And because the keys need to be Strings. It's better to use,

```
val bgColorKey = "bgColorKey"
val textColorKey = "textColorKey"
```

because this makes the code easier to read.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that point. I am accepting your answer since you were the first. Can you please tell how I can load them one after another? I am using 
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(bgColorKey.toString(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if (sharedpreferences.contains(bgColorKey.toString())) {
screen.setBackgroundResource(sharedpreferences.getInt(bgColorKey.toString(), R.drawable.screenshadow))} sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(textcolorKey.toString(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE); if (sharedpreferences.contains(textcolorKey.toString())) {screen.setTextColor(sharedpreferenc.....

Comment: But again problem occurs with one sharedPreference instance. Shoul I use 2? I mean private lateinit var sharedpreferences: SharedPreferences  AND private lateinit var sharedpreferences2: SharedPreferences      like this?

Comment: You shouldn't be using numbers as keys and converting them to strings to use them. That's convoluted. You only need one SharedPreferences. Think of a SharedPreferences as a list of String keys, where each key can store a single value of data.

Answer (score 2):

For storing different values, you must use different key.

Try this:

```
private lateinit var sharedpreferences: SharedPreferences
val bgColorKey = "bgColor"        //key must be a `String` type, required by SharedPreference
val textColorKey= "textColor"     //different thing, diffrent key, they're must be separated

//SAVING CODE:
val editor = sharedpreferences.edit()
editor.putInt(bgColorKey, R.drawable.col1)    //the value you store is a resource id, Int type
editor.putInt(textColorKey, R.color.white)
editor.commit()

//PRINT LINE CODE:
println("bgColorKey value = "+sharedpreferences.getInt(bgColorKey, 0))  
println("textColorKey value = "+sharedpreferences2.getInt(textColorKey, 0))
```

- **SharedPreferences** tutorial: https://youtu.be/fJEFZ6EOM9o

Answer (score 0):

The other answers didn't point it out, but this:

```
val bgColorKey=0

//...

bgColorKey.toString()
```

doesn't return a String key of `"bgColorKey"`. It is converting the `0` into a String with value `"0"`. Since both the keys you defined are based on integer 0, they both are creating the same key `"0"`.

The keys should be unique strings. So something like this:

```
val bgColorKey = "BG_COLOR_KEY"
val textColorKey = "TEXT_COLOR_KEY"
```

Comment: But when I changed one of the keys to 1, it worked. I mean val bgColorKey=0
val textColorKey=1. And the print outputs came different as expected, not any string "0". There, I think your answer is not appropriate

Comment: That works, but it is a convoluted way of doing it that makes the code more error-prone and makes it ambiguous for someone else that reads your code, which would be a problem if you ever collaborate with someone.. You should use the correct tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks bro, I will take this into account